# What is proper color mapping

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

on the material3 color guide, we can see 5 surface colors.

```
Surface
Surface Container Lowest
Surface Container Low
Surface Container
Surface Container High
```

https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/color-roles#c43e5215-3692-4320-87b8-e2747f5a52d3

However when we see material3 color scheme those colors are missing

```
ColorScheme(
    primary: Color,
    onPrimary: Color,
    primaryContainer: Color,
    onPrimaryContainer: Color,
    inversePrimary: Color,
    secondary: Color,
    onSecondary: Color,
    secondaryContainer: Color,
    onSecondaryContainer: Color,
    tertiary: Color,
    onTertiary: Color,
    tertiaryContainer: Color,
    onTertiaryContainer: Color,
    background: Color,
    onBackground: Color,
    surface: Color,
    onSurface: Color,
    surfaceVariant: Color,
    onSurfaceVariant: Color,
    surfaceTint: Color,
    inverseSurface: Color,
    inverseOnSurface: Color,
    error: Color,
    onError: Color,
    errorContainer: Color,
    onErrorContainer: Color,
    outline: Color,
    outlineVariant: Color,
    scrim: Color
)
```

which color should b eused for each surface varian from guide?

Comment: Material 3 color guide and the Material 3 color scheme are two different ways of thinking about color. Color guide is focus on different roles that colors can play in an interface, while color scheme doing focus on specific colors that are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Material 3 color system has introduced [tone-based surface colors](https://material.io/blog/tone-based-surface-color-m3), which provide a more flexible approach compared to the earlier [elevation-based approach](https://m3.material.io/styles/elevation/applying-elevation).
However, the exact mapping between the new tone-based surface colors and the Material 3 [`ColorScheme`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#color-scheme) parameters is not explicitly laid out in the document you mention

There are new [surface container roles](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/color-roles#c43e5215-3692-4320-87b8-e2747f5a52d3) and tokens introduced, which include five colors: "Surface container," "Surface container lowest," "Surface container low," "Surface container," and "Surface container high." The "Surface container" is recommended as the default color role for contained areas against the "surface" color role, ranging from "Surface container lowest" with the lowest emphasis to "Surface container high" with the highest emphasis.

In the context of Flutter, there is mention of using an [`ElevationOverlay.applySurfaceTint` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevationOverlay/applySurfaceTint.html) to apply surface tints based on elevation, where `color` would be the background color, `surfaceTint` is defined in `colorScheme`, and `elevation` would range from 1-5.

However, the exact mapping of these new surface container roles to the [`ColorScheme` parameters](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme/ColorScheme.html) provided in the Material 3 `ColorScheme` code  you shared is not directly specified in the sources. The Material 3 `ColorScheme` seems to have different naming conventions compared to the surface container roles mentioned in the Material 3 color guide.

The `ColorScheme` parameters include color roles like `surface`, `onSurface`, `surfaceVariant`, `onSurfaceVariant`, etc., which might correspond to the surface container roles, but, again, the exact mapping is not clear.

[flutter/issue 98658](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98658) adds, to illustrate the mapping problem:

> > I was playing around with the new Material3 colors and the theme data, and I noticed primary in the ColorScheme is not the same color as the one I provided as colorSchemeSeed. It is significantly darker.
>
> This is expected behavior when using a primary color as seed color. What happens is that the provided color, functions as a single key color to generate 3 different tonal palettes with 13 different tones each.
>
> To be even more exact, it actually generates 6 different tonal palettes under the hood. In addition to primary, secondary and tertiary tonal palettes. It also makes a neutral and neutralVariant one, both with a hint of the seed color in them, more in variant.
> Selected tones from them are used for different surfaces and backgrounds in resulting `ColorScheme`. Then there is also an error tonal palette generated from a fixed red color, used by the error colors in resulting `ColorScheme`.